# Suspensions vs. Loops for C-star algebras

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, c-star-algebras

In the context of C-star algebras, a suspension of a C-star algebra $A$ is defined as $$ SA := \left\{f:\left[0,\,1\right]\to A\,\text{continious}\,\mid\,f\left(0\right)=f\left(1\right)=0_A\right\} $$

On the other hand, to define $\pi_1\left(A, a_0\right)$, we take equivalence classes of continuous maps $S^1\to A$ which map some base-point of $S^1$ (say 1) to a chosen base point, say, $a_0\in A$. Later on we say that if $a_0$ and $a_1$ are in the same path-connected component of $A$, then $\pi_1\left(A, a_0\right)$ and $\pi_1\left(A, a_1\right)$ are isormorphic as groups.

My question is: what is the importance of $0_A$ in the definition of suspension of a C-star algebra? Does it play a similar role as the base point in $\pi_1$, namely, any two points in the same path-connected component will give rise to the same C-star algebra? Or does $0_A$ somehow play a special role? Is the space of loops in $A$ with a fixed base-point equal to the suspension? And what happens if the base-point is allowed to vary (we know that then for the homotopy group we don't get a group structure)

Comment: Wow, is that seriously called the suspension?  To any (algebraic) topologist your $SA$ is our loopspace $\Omega A$.  Our suspension is something very, very different (and is left-adjoint to looping). This terminology is stunning to me, as it is akin to someone deciding that $\sin(\theta)$ should be defined as adjacent/hypotenuse.

Comment: Now I'm curious:  is there some stunning duality that occurs so that loop and suspension coincide for $C^*$-algebras, so it doesn't matter what you call them?  I know nothing about $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: @Randall: I cannot comment on the terminology (only that the name "suspension" has been standard in C$^*$-algebras for decades), but note that C$^*$-algebraists consider $SA$ with the pointwise addition and product, and with the uniform norm, so if I understand Wikipedia's definition correctly, they are fairly different objects. Also, unless I'm again misreading the definitions, the only different between $SA$ above and the topological definition is the requirement of continuity; so, it is a different object but not radically so (depending on point of view, of course).

Comment: @MartinArgerami, at least one thing must hold: when you consider the K theory of vector bundles and do suspensions there, it must be compatible with the C-star algebra picture of these vector bundles and suspensions on those C-star algebras. At Randall: I have not heard the phrase "loop space" in association with C-star algebras. FYI I'm taking my definition from Rordam's textbook.

Comment: One reason for the terminology is that if $A = C(X)$ for a compact Hausdorff space, then $C(SX)$ is the unitization of $SA:= C_0(\mathbb{R})\otimes A$.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Isn‘t https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2783864/suspension-of-c-algebra a counterexample?