# suspension of C$^*$-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I'm trying to understand the connection between suspension of a topological space and suspension of a C$^*$-algebra. The suspension of a topological space $X$ is the product space $X \times I$ (where $I$ is the unit interval) and identify $X \times \{0\} $ to a point and also identify $X \times \{1\} $ to a point, and suspension of a C$^*$-algebra $A$ is 
$$S(A)=\{ f \in C_{0}([0,1],A) | f(0)=f(1)=0\}.$$

If $A$ is a unital abelian C$^*$-algebra then $A$ isomorphic to  $C(X)$ for some compact $X$ , my question is: Is $S(A)$ isomorphic to $C(S(X))$?
I have the same question for mapping cone of topological space and mapping cone of C$^*$-algebra.

Answer (score 2):

No, if $A=C(X)$, we do not have $SA\cong C(SX)$.  Consider $X=\{p\}$, a one-point space.  Then $A=C(X)\cong\mathbb C$ and $SX\cong[0,1]$, so $SA\cong C_0(\mathbb R)$, but $C(SX)\cong C([0,1])$.

Using the same space, we also don't have the desired isomorphism with cones.

Comment: then  how do  suspension of topological space and suspension of c star algebra connect ?

Comment: It's the same word.

Comment: then  is the unitalization of $S(A)$ isomorphic to $C(S(X))$ ??

Comment: I'm sure you can see the intuitive connection, in that for the suspension, we continuously put a copy of the C$^*$-algebra at each point of $[0,1]$, and collapse it at the endpoints, similarly to the suspension of a topological space (and similar analogies hold fort the case of the cone).  But just because the situations are analogous doesn't mean we have the translation you are after.

Comment: And no, in the about situation the unitization of $SA$ is $\cong C(S^1)$ where $S^1$ is the circle.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that $SA=C_0(\mathbb R)$. It looks to me that it is $\{f\in C[0,1]:\ f(0)=f(1)=0\}$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Right, but unless I'm making an awful mistake that's $*$-isomorphic to $C_0((0,1))$, which is $*$-isomorphic to $C_0(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Aweygan Do we maybe have $C(S(X^+)) \cong S(C(X))^+$, where the first $^+$ denotes the one-point compactification and the second one denotes the unitization?

Comment: @HDB It seems to me that $C(\Sigma(X^+))\cong S(C(X))^+$, where $\Sigma$ is the reduced suspension.